# How do I right align multiple left aligned <tspan> in an svg?

Tags: svg

```css
svg {
    width: 100%; height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    font-family: monospace;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
text {
  transform:rotate(180deg) translate(-100px);
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <text y="-85">
       <tspan x="0" text-anchor="start">000012340000</tspan>
       <tspan x="0" text-anchor="start" dy="15">1234</tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```

I want to position multiple lines of left aligned text at the top right of an svg.

The width of the svg is unknown as it's set to 100% width of the parent so I don't think I can use `X` or `dx` coordinates.

I was able to achieve what I wanted by rotating both the entire svg and the text element within it by 180° and applying a negative transform translate but this feels like a hack to me

What is the correct method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think there is a "correct" way to do this. One alternative to your solution is to use x="100%" on the tspans and then translate the text back by the width of your text...

```css
svg {
    width: 100%; height: 100px;
    border: solid 1px blue;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <text y="15" transform="translate(-100 0)">
       <tspan x="100%" text-anchor="start">000012340000</tspan>
       <tspan x="100%" text-anchor="start" dy="15">1234</tspan>
   </text>
</svg>
```